# USB audio: volume too high

Tags: freebsd, audio, oss

The maximum volume of my USB audio ("Dlock USB Sound Adapter 7.1") is far too high (this is bad, because, first, it's dangerous and second it is not possible to adjust the volume finely).

I had this problem under Windows, where I haven't found a real solution.

Under Linux with ALSA and PulseAudio, I found a very good fix, as described [here:](https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/)

We edit the file (this would be the location on Ubuntu and Debian) `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common` and search for the following lines:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all 
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

which we edit to:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
volume-limit = 0.01
override-map.1 = all 
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

where `volume-limit = 0.01` can be adjusted to change the maximum volume.

Now I use FreeBSD, which uses OSS, and I have the same problem again. And I am looking for a similar fix as described in the link.

Comment: Please cite here the main points from the outer link in case that site goes down.

Comment: You can try to tune `sysctl hw.snd.vpc_0db` value. But I have no system to experiment with this setting now.

Comment: @citrin: thank you very much. I set it from 45 to the maximum value 100. It's much better now.